# Thrift Saving Plan (TSP) Share Price Charts

Tags: united-states, tsp

I'm looking for a good resource for TSP share price charts/visualizations.  Something similar to Google Finance's charts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSP.Ninja http://www.tsp.ninja has all the TSP funds with good visualizations that are very similar to Google Finance.

Comment: This site doesn't appear to exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to generate your own charts, you can get up-to-date TSP fund share prices in a Google Docs spreadsheet by "scraping" the data from the HTML of certain TSP webpages. You'll need to do this because the GoogleFinance function does not recognize "private" funds or collective trusts like those of the TSP.

See this thread for tips: [Bogleheads • View topic - GoogleFinance price quotes for TSP Funds](http://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=141547)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to track TSP funds in online portfolio tools is to track the underlying index and know that the results are pretty close.   Not a perfect solution: :(

Source including suggested ETFs: http://finance.yahoo.com/news/breaking-down-tsp-investment-funds-194600393.html

Related, but not exactly what you are looking for, Personal Capital will track your TSP holdings: http://themilitarywallet.com/manage-thrift-savings-plan/